# How to make maven build take version from constant

Tags: java, maven

I have a multi module project. I have introduced a property `app.version` which I use instead of version everywhere in the pom.xml: in version tag and in dependencies in modules part.

I use maven 3.1.1 in Hudson environment.

After substituting written values (1.6.0-SNAPSHOT) with `${app.version}`, the build order that really goes through without error, is gone.

What caused the issue?

I got these kind of warnings in the begin, may it affect?

```
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model     for com.mycompany.project:project-module:jar:2.4.0
[WARNING] 'version' contains an expression but should be a constant. @ com.mycompany.project:project-module:${app.version}, /var/lib/hudson/jobs/myJob TRUNK Maven/workspace/project-module/pom.xml, line 20, column 11
```

I would need to parse too much the pom.xml:s, so the hierarchy is like follows, I give it:

```
main_pom
  |
   --- modules
  |      |
  |       --- all other modules
   --- test        |
                     module A
                   |   |
                   |    module B
                     module C
```

I give for hudson to start from main_pom. It handles main_pom as last. Why?
It starts now from random one in all other modules part, builds the others, then modules, test and main_pom. Why this insane order?

The fail is in module A. It builds that first and not module B.

Correct order would be to start from main_pom -> module B -> module A etc but it starts directly from module A.

**Edit:**

My pom.xmls have the following structure:

```
 <parent>
    <groupId>com.mycompany.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>modules or parent_pom</artifactId>
    <version>${app.version}</version>
    <relativePath>../modules or parent_pom</relativePath>
 </parent>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mycompany.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>some other module</artifactId>
    <version>${app.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: would be good if you could share your current pom.xml content instead and what changes did you introduce there. Also how are you trying to build the project using the introduced property?

Comment: Made changes. Please, see my update.

Comment: The details are insufficient still. Could you specify what is the expected order and why? and what order are they getting executed in and after what changes.

Comment: Also would recommend you to visit https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html ReactorSorting for how the order is resolved.

Comment: you need  to share the parent pom.xml file content here to get things clear and how does building A prior ro building B effects you?

Comment: Found the issue. See answer.

Comment: So, it was nothing about the dependencies and their order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maven 3.2.1 or later is [required](https://axelfontaine.com/blog/dead-burried.html) to cleanly use variables in the main `<version>` corrdinate of a pom file.

Comment: Works perfectly in newest maven.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following, and things started to flow:

main_pom:

```
<version>${app.version}</version>
```

all others:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.mycompany.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>modules or parent_pom</artifactId>
    <version>${app.version}</version>
    <relativePath>../modules or parent_pom</relativePath>
</parent>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mycompany.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>some other module</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version> <---- here was before ${app.version}
</dependency>
```

Use of `project.version` instead of `app.version` property on dependencies made the trick.

Comment: Sorry but the question in the first place doesn't have such info as presented in the answer.

Comment: In written form yes, not code example. Sorry about that. "all other places where is number in written form" is quite obscure.